# Disable all mondays from date picker .ext

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ext.net, next.js

I´m trying to disable of mondays from a date picker in ext.js, but no sure how to make it without implement an array. cuz an array limite the range & days, & i want to disable for ever.

aspx:

```
    <ext:DatePicker ID="DPdate" runat="server" Format="d/m/y">
                                    <DirectEvents>
                                        <Select OnEvent="LoadTableByDate">
                                            <EventMask Msg="Cargando 

Disponiblidad de salas" ShowMask="true" />
                                            <ExtraParams>
                                                <ext:Parameter Value="Ext.Date.format(App.DPdate.getValue(), 'd/m/Y')" Mode="Raw" Name="DPpicker" />
                                            </ExtraParams>
                                       </Select>
                                </DirectEvents>
                     </ext:DatePicker>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the DisabledDays setting to disable given week days:

```
<ext:DatePicker ID="DPdate" runat="server" Format="d/m/y" DisabledDays="1" />
```

Source: [Ext.NET 4.2.1 API docs on the DatePicker component](http://docs.ext.net/dc/dc4/class_ext_1_1_net_1_1_date_picker.html#a0e261c7726d8134006c533f6dc5b0d1a)

Answer (score 0):

**ASPX**

```
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" ondayrender="Calendar1_DayRender"> 
</asp:Calendar>
```

**Code Behind**

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e){
    if (e.Day.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday){
        e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
    } 
 }
```

Comment: Thank you @fluffy for ur response.  How can i implement ondayRender property in datepicker in ext.net?.  cause previous solution no applies for DATEPICKERS in ext.net

Comment: You can disable days by putting disabledDays: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6] in your datefield conf.